# How to reset Obout combobox on click

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, combobox, obout

i am using obout combobox, the problem is, i want, when i click to change the text, the old text should be removed, because it remains there and append the text which i enter, does anybody have any idea, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad, the obout control generates a div of class "ob_iCboITCN" that contains a textbox.  what I did was:

```
$(".ob_iCboITCN").click(function() {
    $(this).find("input[type='text']").val("");
});
```

I'm using icons so the above doesn't clear the icon but I'm fine with it.  have you gotten this control to work ok?  I'm struggling... please see [my article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005559/response-out-of-sequence)

Comment: i found the solution, there is a built in property of obout combobox to do that, no need of using jquery,