# Response out of sequence

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, obout

I'm using the Obout.com MVC controls and have included the following code in one of my views:

```
@{
   Html.Obout(new ComboBox("Languages") {
       Width = 175,
       SelectedIndex = (int) ViewData["DefaultLanguage"] - 1,
       ShowSelectedImage = true
       }
   );
}
```

I'm doing it that way because my original attempt failed:

```
@Html.Obout(new ComboBox("Languages") { Width = 175, SelectedIndex = (int) ViewData["DefaultLanguage"] - 1, ShowSelectedImage = true })
```

...it seems I need to use the `@{}` structure.  However, when the output gets generated, the code that `Html.Obout()` generates comes ahead of all other output.  the `<!DOCTYPE html>` and the real page follows the control's output.  is this a function of the `@{}` structure, or is it some issue with the control itself?

Comment: Ask the company for a Razor version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this method was designed for ASPX views and writes directly to `HttpContextBase.Response.OutputStream`.

Since Razor buffers its output in `WebPageBase.Output`, you will not easily be able to use these helpers in Razor.
You could put them in a separate ASCX partial view, and they will work.

Depending on how the helpers are implemented, you may be able to force them to write to `WebPageBase.Output`; since I don't use Obout, I don't know.

Comment: I did try your suggestion and it worked, calling it as a partial view, however the control generates obscene output and created scrollbars in my div with a bunch of empty space... not sure wtf.  I ended up going with a jQuery solution but thanks for the useful reply.

Answer (score 1):

The Razor compatible version of the Obout MVC ComboBox will be available soon:
http://forum.obout.com/yaf_postsm2112_Examples-pleease.aspx#post2112